# How do I use the shutil to copy a file?

Tags: python

I am new to python. Can someone explain me why my below code shows error?

```
import shutil
shutil.copy('E:\\python test\\python\\program\\123.txt', "E:\\python test")
```

I want to copy the file into another folder, but instead I get the error `'module' object has no attribute 'copy'`.

Comment: Do you have any files you may have named "shutil.py" that are getting in the way?

Comment: `print shutil.__file__`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
import os
os.system ("copy E:\\python test\\python\\program\\123.txt E:\\python test")
```